# sending multiple products to paypal using symfony

Tags: php, symfony, loops, paypal, payum

I am working with Symfony Payum bundle to send orders to PayPal and so far it is working fine with single product

Suppose my single product array looks like this

```
$orderDetails = array(
        'productID' => '10',
        'fname' => 'First Name',
        'lname' => 'Last Name',
        'phone' => '111',
        'clientemail' => 'xyz@abc.com',
        'name' => 'Product Name',
        'description' => 'The Product description.',
        'price' => 8.64,
        'currency_symbol' => '$',
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'clientId' => '222',
        'payment_option' => $paymentName


);
```

Then the following code works perfectly fine

```
$storage = $this->get('payum')->getStorage('ClickTeck\featuresBundle\Entity\Orders');
/** @var $paymentDetails Orders */
$paymentDetails = $storage->create();


$paymentDetails->setClientFname($orderDetails['fname']);
$paymentDetails->setClientLname($orderDetails['lname']);
$paymentDetails->setClientPhone($orderDetails['phone']);
$paymentDetails->setClientEmail($orderDetails['clientemail']);
$paymentDetails->setNumber($orderDetails['productID']);
$paymentDetails->setDescription($orderDetails['description']);
$paymentDetails->setCurrencyCode($orderDetails['currency']);
$paymentDetails->setTotalAmount($orderDetails['price']);
$paymentDetails->setClientId($orderDetails['clientId']);
$paymentDetails->setPaymentOption($orderDetails['payment_option']);



$paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = $orderDetails['currency'];
$paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = $orderDetails['price'];
$paymentDetails['NOSHIPPING'] = Api::NOSHIPPING_NOT_DISPLAY_ADDRESS;
$paymentDetails['REQCONFIRMSHIPPING'] = Api::REQCONFIRMSHIPPING_NOT_REQUIRED;
$paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0'] = Api::PAYMENTREQUEST_ITERMCATEGORY_DIGITAL;
$paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'] = $orderDetails['price'];
$paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0'] = $orderDetails['name'];
$paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0'] = $orderDetails['description'];
$storage->update($paymentDetails);
$captureToken = $this->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken(
    $paymentName,
    $paymentDetails,
    'payment_done'
);
$paymentDetails['INVNUM'] = $paymentDetails->getId();
$storage->update($paymentDetails);
return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
```

However if I have multiple products like the array below, then how to handle this?

```
$paymentName = 'paypal';

$orderDetails = array(
    array(
        'productID' => '10',
        'fname' => 'First Name',
        'lname' => 'Last Name',
        'phone' => '111',
        'clientemail' => 'xyz@abc.com',
        'name' => 'Product Name',
        'description' => 'The Product description.',
        'price' => 8.64,
        'currency_symbol' => '$',
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'clientId' => '222',
        'payment_option' => $paymentName
    ),
    array(
        'productID' => '10',
        'fname' => 'First Name',
        'lname' => 'Last Name',
        'phone' => '111',
        'clientemail' => 'xyz@abc.com',
        'name' => 'Product Name',
        'description' => 'The Product description.',
        'price' => 8.64,
        'currency_symbol' => '$',
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'clientId' => '222',
        'payment_option' => $paymentName
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop through the items to generate that portion of the API request dynamically.  So it would be something like this.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($orderDetails as $orderItem)
{
    $paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY' . $i] = Api::PAYMENTREQUEST_ITERMCATEGORY_DIGITAL;
    $paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' . $i] = $orderItem['price'];
    $paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME' . $i] = $orderItem['name'];
    $paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC' . $i] = $orderItem['description'];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It does make sense to loop through it. Have you ever used payum for symfony framework

Comment: No, I actually have my own [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) that I've been maintaining for years now.  I handle things like order items and all of that for you within the library.  It has nearly every API PayPal offers ready to go, and it has a functional sample and empty template for every one.  All you have to do is fill in the params with your own data.  I'd recommend taking a look.  I think you'll like it.

Comment: this seems to be sending only one item to paypal, bottom part of array

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the help.

Answer (score -1):

just like that:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($orderDetails); $i++) {
  $paymentDetails->setClientEmail($orderDetails[$i]['clientemail']);
  $paymentDetails->setDescription($orderDetails[$i]['description']);
  $paymentDetails->setCurrencyCode($orderDetails[$i]['currency']);
  $paymentDetails->setTotalAmount($orderDetails[$i]['price']);
  $paymentDetails[$payment.$i.'_CURRENCYCODE'] = $orderDetails[$i]['currency'];
  $paymentDetails[$payment.$i.'_AMT'] = $orderDetails[$i]['price'];
  $paymentDetails['NOSHIPPING'] = Api::NOSHIPPING_NOT_DISPLAY_ADDRESS;
  $paymentDetails['REQCONFIRMSHIPPING'] = Api::REQCONFIRMSHIPPING_NOT_REQUIRED;
  $paymentDetails[$lpayment.$i.'_ITEMCATEGORY0'] = Api::PAYMENTREQUEST_ITERMCATEGORY_DIGITAL;
  $paymentDetails[$payment . $i . '_PAYMENTREQUESTID'] = "CART26488-PAYMENT".$i;
  $paymentDetails[$payment . $i . '_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID'] = "etochavez-facilitator@gmail.com";
  $paymentDetails[$lpayment.$i.'_AMT0'] = $orderDetails[$i]['price'];
  $paymentDetails[$lpayment.$i.'_NAME0'] = $orderDetails[$i]['name'];
  $paymentDetails[$lpayment.$i.'_DESC0'] = $orderDetails[$i]['description'];
}
```

Comment: forget to put the top: 
    $payment = "PAYMENTREQUEST_";
    $lpayment = "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_";

Comment: This would not be accurate as I'm looking at it now.  You need to remember there are 2 separate things here:  you can have multiple payments, which is where the 0 comes from in a parameter like PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT.  Each payment could then have multiple items, which is why you have parameters like L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0.  You would need to track $i separate from $n and use one for payments and one for items.